# Any $n$-element arithmetic progression which sum is $n!$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In any $n$-element arithmetic progression which sum is $n!$ exsists one or more elements equals $(n-1)!$. Is it true when:

```
a) n=2013
b) n=2014
c) n=2015
d) n=2016
```

I suppose that I should use property of parity but I don't have idea how. I will grateful for yours help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first two lines aren't clear: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let the progression be $a + k\cdot d, \; 0 \leqslant k < n$. Then the sum of the terms in the progression is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a + k\cdot d) = n\cdot a + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}d = n\left(a + \frac{(n-1)d}{2}\right).$$

So the sum is $n!$ if and only if

$$(n-1)! = a + \frac{(n-1)d}{2}.$$

In particular, (at least) one of $(n-1)$ and $d$ must be even. If $n$ is odd, then we have

$$(n-1)! = a + \frac{n-1}{2}\cdot d$$

in the progression. If $n$ is even, then

$$(n-1)! = a + (n-1)\frac{d}{2}$$

is in the progression if and only if there is a $k$ with $k\cdot d = (n-1)\cdot \frac{d}{2} \iff (2k - n + 1)d = 0$, so if and only if $d = 0$.